# jspdf showing wrong css styles on downloaded PDF in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, yarnpkg, jspdf

I am trying to download a pdf file using jsPDF. The issue I am facing here is the CSS styling doesn't appear in the downloaded pdf. Below is the method I am using to download the pdf. I am using jsPDF in vuejs. Please help me find how can I add CSS styles in the downloaded pdf

main_file.vue

```
<template>
 <div>
   <v-btn @click="downloadPDF">
    Download
   </v-btn>
  <Download v-show="false" ref="DownloadComp" />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 import Download from 'views/letter.vue'
 export default {
  components: {
    Download
  },
  methods: {
    downloadPDF () {
      let pdfName = 'download-file'; 
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.html(this.$refs.DownloadComp.$el.innerHTML, { callback: (doc) => {
            doc.save();
          }
      })
    }
  }
 }
</script>
```

letter.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="sectional">Official Letter
    </div>
    <p class="intro">Address</p> 
  </div>
</template>
```